# Checking a single checkbox will result in every checkbox getting check

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How do I solve this?

This is the code for my checkbox.

```
<ion-list *ngIf="items">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let driver of items">
        <ion-label>{{driver.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="driverSelect"
        [checked]="items.includes(driver)" item-right></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nNUo.jpg

Comment: It might be useful if you describe what you've tried so far. Also including the issue in the question as well as the title may be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
<ion-list *ngIf="items">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let driver of items;let i = index ">
        <ion-label>{{driver.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="items[i]"
        [checked]="items.includes(driver)" item-right></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

You have to make model name different with each checkbox